# How can I make a Typescript type composed of public members of another type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Using Typescript 4.3.5

How can I specify a type made of the public members/properties of another? Consider:

```js
class Thing {
  public name: string
  private secret: string

  public greet(): string {}
  private curse(): string {}
}
```

Now I'd like to define this type:

```js
type PublicProps<Thing> = {
  name: string
  greet(): string
}
```

How do I make this generic?

```js
type PublicProps<T> = ?
```

Comment: Try `type PublicProps<T> = {[key in keyof T]: T[key]}`. This will work, because private properties are not included in `keyof T`

Comment: @AlexChashin you're right.  If you wish, post this as an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 0):

I used this generic form:

```
type PublicInterface<T> = { [key in keyof T]: T[key] };
```

Given your example, `PublicInterface<Thing>` would be a type with only the `name` and `greet()` members.

This works because `keyof T` exposes only public members of T.

---

This solution was [originally posted by Alex Chashin in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68967275/howto-make-typescript-type-composed-of-public-members-of-another-type#comment121886933_68967275). I came across this while researching for this feature.